# Using the try catch statement to print out statements

Tags: java, junit

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
         //some code over here
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(e.toString() == null)
        {
               System.out.print("Test Case: Successful");
        }
        else
        {
               System.out.println("Test Case: Failed");
               System.out.println("Failing Reason: "+ e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have the above code. 
However, when executing the JUnit.
Nothing was printed into the console.

Did I do anything wrong? Or is it that i cannot use System.out.println in JUnit.

So I have a second question:
Is it possible to print out the total amount of time taken to complete the JUnit test?

Comment: try e.printStackTrace instead of e.toString and use .length instead of ==

Comment: Which kind of Exception object are you catching ? The default `toString` of `Exception` (inherited from `Throwable`) is never null.

Comment: Why do you think you need to reinvent what JUnit will do for you? Imagine if you had to add this to *every* test case.... and with this code, JUnit won't even detect that the test has failed.

Comment: "Nothing was printed into the console." Presumably the code in the `try` block doesn't throw an `Exception`.

Comment: To print an error From Exception just type **e.printStackTrace();**

Comment: As you testing, you want to find **Exception** in a Program/Application.
Suppose, If there is no error/exception in this Program/Application then you get **Nothing**. i.e It always go through **try block** execute smoothly and In you program all of your print statement in catch block and also It never ever throws Exception because this program logic 100% correct what you trying testing & want some issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in the `catch` block will only run if the code in the `try` block throws an exception.  As you have it coded, it is not going to print anything out unless an exception is throw.  This is likely what you meant:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
         //some code over here

         // last line of try block
         System.out.print("Test Case: Successful"); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Test Case: Failed");
        System.out.println("Failing Reason: "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What ways can i  display the total amount of time used to complete the JUnit test case?

Comment: Although the OP has accepted this as a fix for the OP's code, I would strongly recommend not to go down this path. The JUnit framework probably handles this much better.

Answer (score 5):

This code doesn't make sense.

- If no exception is thrown, no exception is thrown, so you won't end up in the `catch` block; so there isn't a way you'd end up there in the "successful" case (unless you're testing explicitly for throwing an exception whose `getMessage()` returns `null`, which is... hmm; and in that case you should have a `fail()` as the last line of the `try`)
- JUnit already handles failures for you. If your approach were the "right" way to do it, you'd have to put this code in *every* test case. What a lot of repeated code.
- If the code in the `try` block fails by throwing an `Exception`, you catch and swallow the problem. Sure, it gets printed to the console, but JUnit has no means of capturing that, so it looks like the test passes. (It will still fail properly if an `Error` or other `Throwable` is thrown).

In short: just get rid of your `try`/`catch` block, leaving the code in the `try`, and let the testing framework do exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: Because I wanted to print the results into a text file, so that the user can know if the test has completed smoothly.

Comment: @LanYungLee you're trying to solve this in the wrong place. This is something you want to solve in the framework, not in the test cases run by the framework. Otherwise, you're just going to have to repeat yourself again and again - and, to reiterate, you're breaking JUnit's functionality like this.